# Unable to access newly api service from developer portal in Azure api management

Tags: java, api, azure, azure-api-management

While trying to access newly created rest API service from developer portal in Azure API management, I am getting below error

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the call to your API from the developer console in the Developer portal?

Comment: Can you provide the trace of the call?  That might help identify the issue.

Comment: Why don't you attach the code illustrating the way you are accessing that service, and perhaps of service itself?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error code, per my experience, I think the issue was caused by using an incomplete url in your request.

For example, there is an API `https://xxxx.azure-api.net/echo` in the deveploer portal `https://xxxx.azure-api.net/admin/services`, as below.

[image]

If I just did the `GET` request for the url, I got the same error as yours, because the name `echo` is only the API service name, not a complete resource name. In the example, the complete url should be `https://xxxx.azure-api.net/echo/resource?param1=sample[&...]`, please see below.

[image]

So please check your API definition and use the related complete APIs for your requests.